# Image hosted internally inaccessible on MS Teams client

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

We have enabled Bot Framework app in our corporate Teams and we want to use `AdaptiveCards` to present rich content to users. For example, we are sending `AdaptiveImage` containing url pointing to corporate image store.

Sample code:

```
new AdaptiveImage
{
    Size = AdaptiveImageSize.Small,
    Url = new Uri("https://corporate-storage.com/images/image1.png"), // This is image not hosted publicly.
    AltText = "Some text"
}
```

This works fine in WebChat client as the url is just appended to the `src` attribute of the `img` HTML tag. However in MS Teams it seems that it is preprocessed by some weird proxy / MITM and the url results in:

`https://urlp.asm.skype.com/v1/url/content?url=https%3a%2f%2fcorporate-proxy.com%2fimages%2fimage1.png`

When we try to browse the url to see where why the picure is not rendered we see empty page with 502 response code in debugger.

Is there a way how to force MS Teams to not alter `src` attributes of pictures.

Comment: Although I can't help with your question, it's worth noting that I suspect they're doing some security scanning, caching, and CDN distribution on the image, so overall this works more in our favor than against it. Can you not host your images outside of the company network? Maybe Azure Blob storage?

Answer (score 1):

For rendering image in adaptive card, it has to be hosted in public content-delivery network (CDN). Here the [official document link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#common-properties-for-all-cards).

It worked in WebChat client because in browser your authentication is already cached where as in Teams App there is no cache and the image requires authentication.

You need to host the image in public domain or Azure Blob storage to make it work.

Comment: Problem with hosting the pictures in CDN is that I have to render the user's avatar in specific use cases and as you can already imagine, the amount of these users (pictures) is pretty big. Next up, since our bot is hosted in Azure, I cannot connect to on-premise network to access the pictures and upload them into CND - even with gateway this would be never approved by our security department. I was hoping that I could simply flag our bot as trusted to prevent this OOB proxyfying. It is strange that Teams is MS' recommended on-prem communicator, yet you cannot share on-prem content on it...

Answer (score 0):

I also have not found a way to resolve that, some gays also ask about this problem.

So, I use [tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/) to load a JS code piece like this.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://teams.microsoft.com/*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=microsoft.com
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    setInterval(function(){
        $('img').each(function(){
            if($(this).attr('src').startsWith("https://urlp.asm.skype.com/v1/url/content?url=https%3a%2f%2fp.datadoghq.com")){
                let datadogUrl=$(this).attr('src').replace("https://urlp.asm.skype.com/v1/url/content?url=","")
                datadogUrl=decodeURIComponent(datadogUrl)
                $(this).attr('src', datadogUrl);
            }
        })
    }, 5000);

})();
```

And use [Teams Web](https://teams.microsoft.com/), not Teams App.