# How to send rich text with image using Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

Recently we are building a application which send message through Microsoft BotFramework API

We are using the API as below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#send-to-conversation

The following API allow us to send text or attachments by passing activities as parameters.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#activity-object

Everything works well, and on our client side, text and attachments can be received normally as below.

[image]

However, recently we have to send rich text which contains text and image info. For example, admin user want to send text and pasted image together to client user.
So we are considering sending text with markdown style with image info like this

```
text:aaaaa![test](https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/976/cpsprodpb/C448/production/_117684205_lotus.jpg "test")
```

however, client user can only get the info as below. On our client side who use Microsoft Teams App, the image info could not be parsed normally, although image src is a public link.

[image]

I know by using attachment image can be send successfully, but what we need is to send a rich text which has ordered text and image as below

[image]

Could someone tell me how to find a solution?

Comment: Where you have stored this markdown text ? in Qna Maker or Seperate Portal ? also are you testing in desktop app or IOS app ?

Comment: I send markdown text as a request body for the following api
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#create-conversation


Text filed in the Activity object

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#activity-object

Comment: So you are directly passing the markdown through that api ?

Comment: I have given the solution and it's related to extra content issue and you can verify from your end.

Comment: Yes, I passed the markdown as a text through that api.

Comment: Activity objects or request body will change based on the channels ( MS Teams, emulator,etc). Please verify that part as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the given markdown syntax in MS Team and it's rendering the correct output. Here through QnA maker I have verified & tested the flow instead of the API that you have given. The issue is not related to Teams APP and look like the markdown has one extra text in the url probably that creating the problem while posting attachment in the MS Teams through request body.

**Your Markdown Syntax**

Remove the extra "test" content from url.

text:aaaaa![test](https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/976/cpsprodpb/C448/production/_117684205_lotus.jpg **"test"**)

**Markdown Syntax**

```
text:aaaaa![test](https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/976/cpsprodpb/C448/production/_117684205_lotus.jpg)
```

**Output**

[image: ![enter image description here]

**Note:** QnA maker will automatically remove this kind of extra content from the url during the build & test process.

Comment: Thank you for your awesome comment!
Could you post all of your test parameters like type and activities, I corrected my markdown syntax but still not work. Maybe other parameters is also incorrect

Comment: Actually I posted the wrong api reference which is create conversation
We are using the following api actually
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#send-to-conversation

Comment: I found why the url is not shown is caused by MS add an prev header in front of original src url
https://urlp.asm.skype.com/v1/url/content?url=https%3a%2f%2fcorporate-proxy.com%2fimages%2fimage1.png


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60152827/image-hosted-internally-inaccessible-on-ms-teams-client

Comment: While posting any activities into any channels you required a proper activity object ( Request Body ), Probably you can verify the activity object of team, different channels have different activity objects.

Comment: @ZhongweiXu I don't think it's related to internal url issue as per your comment then QnA maker side also will get the same issue. Better to check the channel specific activity object.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using Language Generation file in your project and using Adaptive cards. You can find samples here  https://adaptivecards.io/samples/

You can design your own adaptive card in your designer https://adaptivecards.io/designer/

and create a json file which you will have to place inside your project Template folder.  (or respective folder directory that you have registered)

Once you are done creating and placing the files, follow the code to call the adaptive card

```
await dc.Context.SendActivityAsync(ActivityFactory.FromObject(_templates.Evaluate("yourlgintent"))).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

in your `filename.lg` file

```
# yourlgintent
[Activity 
      Attachments = ${ActivityAttachment(json(fromFile('yourfilename.json')), 'adaptiveCard')}
]
```

OR

You can directly call it in a method

````
# yourlgintent
[Activity 
      Attachments = ${ActivityAttachment(json(yourlgintentJson()), 'adaptiveCard')}
]

#yourlgintentJson
    - ```
    {
        "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
        "version": "1.3",
        "body": [
            {
                "type": "Container",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "wrap": true,
                        "text": "As your virtual assistant, I love answering your questions. Having said that, I am learning continuously to expand my knowledge.",
                        "height": "stretch"
                    }
                ],
                "spacing": "Large"
            }
        ]
    }
````

Comment: Thank you for your directions and hint!
Adaptive card is the final choose I think

Comment: Thank You. You can accept this as answer :-)

Comment: Sorry I mean, if there are no choose, I will use adaptive card

Answer (score 1):

And yes, If you are looking to get image from your QnA, then follow the below code

Inside your QnAMaker portal ,

```
Your Answer. [Image](https://URLTotheimage.com/Images/image.png)
```

This should give image within your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the sollution
https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/4121

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.